# Nexus 5X Android 6.0 can't recognize in the computer

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow, fastboot

I have Nexus 5X, and I had everything working but suddenly 
I can only charge the phone but I can't see it on the computer. 
I tried 2 different cables and 3 different computers and OS(Windows 7, 8, and Ubuntu)

And I checked and the device is in MTP mode. 
I even tried with adb/recovery/fastboot(in the bootloader)

these are the device properties:

```
Android version: 6.0 Marshmallow.
Build number: MDB08L.
Kernel: 3.10.73-g60cf314.
```

btw, I checked in `dmesg` on my ubuntu when I connected and I've found this:

```
[36357.340506] usb 1-2: new low-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
```

P.S. I even tried doing a factory reset and it didn't helped.

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb`

Comment: nothing new than before i connected

Comment: It is wrong place to ask this question. It's not about programming!